# Serializing with Newtonsoft JsonConvert fails on particular set of properties

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize an object tree to a json string.  The object tree is complex and generally serializes without problems with exception of one set of properties that are objects coming from a different .DLL.  Is there anyway I can serialize those too?

Here's the code that serializes:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exe.Value, settings);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(folderCache, exe.Value.AccountId + ".txt"), json);
```

Here is the type of the class properties of which do NOT get serialized:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceManagementNS)]
public class Deployment : IExtensibleDataObject
```

exe.Value is an EntityFramework based model object that is defined something like this (it is deep in structure)

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Account))]
public partial class AccountUser: IObjectWithChangeTracker, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Somewhere deep in the tree there is a property called AzureDeployment that does not get serialized:

```
    public Deployment AzureDeployment { get; set; }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't the Deployment class definition need to marked as [Serializable]

Comment: None of my other classes are

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: No exception, just missing properties in the saved file and obviously they do not get restored back

Comment: We don't know the object ((exe.Value) you try to serialize, we don't know anything about your *other* ddl, the types of properties that don't get serialized. Do you really expect an answer?

Comment: Well, you can ask for further clarifications.  Why does the object type matter?  It gets serialized OK.  Only its single property doesn't.  I was hoping that the secret would lie in the Deployment's object attributes/inheritance structure.  Or perhaps that two objects live in different namespaces?

Comment: @Igorek You hope something but maybe we have other ideas. Why do you insist on not giving any further information. Isn't there a probability that you are completetely on the wrong track and others can find a different way?

Comment: I dont, just noone asked.  You simply stated: "do you really expect an answer" :)  Edited the original question with the definition of root class (exe.Value)

Comment: @Igorek Just read the previous part of `do you really expect an answer`? Isn't there any request for further information. I am going to vote as `not constructive`

Comment: @I4V Feel free to mark it as you wish.  But do understand that making comments the way you've made them is NOT constructive. Your comment did not request further information.  Your comment criticized my question ending with "do you really expect an answer?".  I've been on SO long enough and have seen plenty of questions that deserve such a treatment.  My question was not one of those questions.  If you want to help, do.  Otherwise, kindly find somewhere else to criticize.

Comment: @Igorek OK. You might be right, but just think of this: after more than hour, no one even tried to give an answer. Do you think you faced with a problem no one knows? Doesn't that show the quality of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to tag the non-serializing entity with [DataMember]